# Framework JS para edições de imagem

Tags: imagem, editor

Bom dia,

Alguém conhece algum framework JS onde eu selecione alguma imagem e faça edições em cima dela?

Como por exemplo, adicionar algumas setas, marcações, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Existem varias formas de se fazer isso, e você provavelmente não irá encontrar um que faça tudo o que você quer, da forma que quer, o que pode fazer, é pegar um que faça pouco e melhorar/ajustar para a sua necessidade.

Um que você pode usar é o [StudioJS](https://github.com/imazen/studiojs) que é bem simples de utilizar.

```
<div class="studio1" ></div>

<script>

        $(function () {
            $('div.studio1').ImageStudio({ url: '/image.jpg?width=900' });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Eu já vi esse, mas o que eu preciso não é algo muito complexo não.

Só preciso que carregue uma foto, dê para adicionar umas setas (para apontar algo) e que dê para escrever um comentário.

Não preciso de edição, recorte de imagem, nada disso.

Comment: Então você consegue fazer isso na unha e depois gerar uma imagem em cima de tudo o que fez. Vou fazer um exemplo simples.

Comment: Opa, eu agradeceria se você fizesse um exemplo =)